# Is it possible to record audio on Android while lock screen is on?

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

I'm writing a sound recorder app and I'm wondering if it's possible to activate the MediaRecorder while the phone has its lock screen up. If so, is it just a matter of a special permission or something else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try using **PowerManager** class with permission **android.permission.WAKE_LOCK**.

you can find more [Here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Lock screen does not affect the working of services in an application. So if you are using a service, then your recording will proceed. However, if your phone is in standby, then it may not work. In that case, just grab a wakelock to keep the CPU alive and function your needs. However, grabbing a wakelock affects battery, so you must use it intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

These days (Android 11 or later), this should no longer be possible:

> Note: On devices running Android 9 (API level 28) or higher, **apps running in the background cannot access the microphone**. Therefore, your app should record audio only when it's in the foreground or when you include an instance of MediaRecorder in a foreground service.

[1] https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder

> Restricted access to location, camera, and microphone
> To help protect user privacy, Android 11 (API level 30) introduces limitations to when a foreground service can access the device's location, camera, or microphone. When your app starts a foreground service while the app is running in the background, the foreground service has the following limitations:
> ...
> The foreground service **cannot access the microphone** or camera.

[2] https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services