# How to capture an Image and record a voice, through a service, even if the device is locked?

Tags: android

I am working on my app and i am developing android anti lost app. So how can i make a service that will capture image or record voice even when device is locked ,I have figured out how to trigger that service.
But how to write code that will do the job even if device is locked?

Comment: post your codes what you have tried

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13578391/4106398

Comment: @vm345 can you just show me a simple example which wake lock and capture image in service and i can also use device administrator api i have already implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making an anti lost app the service must run the whole time . I don't think that lock screen will affect the workings once the service is on still you should try using PowerManager class with permission android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.....

refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager for more details

for camera you can refer to https://www.javatpoint.com/android-camera-tutorial

for voice recorder you can refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audio_capture.htm

Comment: thanks one more thing all i need now is i will initiate some activity through service is it possible for service to display activity when device is locked?

Comment: i don't think it is possible what i know is " you can add notifications while its locked on the screen that can happen" search if it is possible i will comment if i find anything ..... please vote up the ans and accept it by clicking on the tick if it helped you

Comment: k you can refer to for activity display on locked screen  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325587/how-can-i-display-the-activity-when-device-is-locked

Comment: Thanks i think i can now figure things with the help you provided :D